# In Metro, how can I get my instance defined in resource?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

If I define a class named MyClass in xaml, I can retrieve it in code-behind by .net framework like this,

```
Application.Current.FindResource("keyName") as MyClass;
```

the "keyName" is my assignment to x:key property defined in xaml.

But in metro it doesn't work anymore. Could someone please tell me how to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in msdn forum answered it. The [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/39810d22-9219-4fe4-b934-8d5a63427730) was so simple that made me embarrassed.

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass)Application.Current.Resources["keyName"];
```

So you can get self-defined resource in App.xaml.

Comment: You should post the actual answer in your answer.  Going to flag this as "not being an answer" since all you did was link to the thread in question.

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you for your suggestion. I already edited it.